# Save data as .Rds with variable instead of constant names

Tags: r, save

I have an object called NKLA with class `xts`/`zoo` and I would like to save it in a subfolder of the `setwd` as an `.Rds` file.

However, when I use variables instead of constants as names, it only stores an 57 byte file (probably just the file name `NKLA` with no data inside of the file). This a simplified version of what I try to do:

```
library(svDialogs)
library(quantmod)

# Store object name in variable ticker
ticker <- toupper(dlgInput("Please enter a new or not loaded ticker.")$res)

# Get ticker symbol from the Internet and store its name in variable yahooSymbol
yahooSymbol <- getSymbols.yahoo(ticker, env = globalenv())

# Store path and file name in a variable called saveRDSfile
saveRDSfile <- paste0("./", rdsFilesFolder, "/", ticker, ".Rds")

# But when I try to save the file, it only creates a 57 byte file (probably just the name of the file)
saveRDS(yahooSymbol, file = saveRDSfile)
```

When I use the following code, the `xts`/`zoo` is correctly saved as an `.Rds` file:

```
saveRDS(NKLA, file = saveRDSfile)
```

But I don't want to hardcode each filename.

My question:

- What code do I have to write so that `saveRDS` uses the variable `yahooSymbol` to point to the downloaded `xts` file instead of using the characters it contains?

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Comment: Try `yahooSymbol <- getSymbols.yahoo(ticker, env = NULL)`. That will return the value itself

Comment: @MrFlick: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the solution you gave does not seem to work. It renders the following, for example: ```Warning: Unable to import “OBSN.SW”.
using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct```

Comment: Maybe `yahooSymbol <- getSymbols.yahoo(ticker, auto.assign=FALSE)` instead.

Comment: @MrFlick your solution works, but generates another issue which is that instead of having the ticker's name as ```data.frame``` name, it is called ```yahooSymbol```. I need the ```data.frame``` name to remain whatever the name it got when it was downloaded (e.g., ```TSLA```). In other words, the same way variable ```saveRDSfile``` points to path and filename, I would like ```yahooSymbol``` to point to the object in the ```saveRDS(yahooSymbol, file = saveRDSfile)``` command (e.g., ```TSLA``` data frame).